# If else statement not functioning properly

Tags: java, if-statement

af, ae, and be are all integers and here I am checking to see if they equal 0.  If not, I want to return null.  If they do equal zero, I want to return glorpPoly.  For some reason though, it always returns null even when the condition is satisfied... does anyone know why? all these values are of a type our teacher created called MyDouble.  all of them have been initialized to this value, but it still doesn't work.

```
MyDouble af = a.multiply(poly.c);
    MyDouble ae = a.multiply(poly.b);
    MyDouble bf = b.multiply(poly.c);
    MyDouble cf = c.multiply(poly.c);
    MyDouble be = b.multiply(poly.b);
    MyDouble ad = a.multiply(poly.a);
    MyDouble ce = c.multiply(poly.b);
    MyDouble bd = b.multiply(poly.c);
    MyDouble cd = c.multiply(poly.a);
    //Adding the the variables and creating new coefficients
    MyDouble newA = af;
    MyDouble newB = ae.add(bf);
    MyDouble newC = cf.add(be).add(ad);
    MyDouble newD = ce.add(bd);
    MyDouble newE = cd;
    MyDouble zero = new MyDouble(0)
if(af != zero && ae !=zero && be != zero){

        return null;
    }
    else{
        MartianPolynomial glorpPoly = new MartianPolynomial(newC,newD,newE);
        return glorpPoly;
    }
}
```

Comment: `0 != zero`. Does this even compile?

Comment: Shouldn't it be if(af != 0 && ae != 0 && be != 0) (assuming these are ints?

Comment: Can't you do: `if ((af * ae * be) != 0)`?

Comment: `static final int zero = 1;` /* chuckles */

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl what is the integers are `-2`, `2`, and `0` respectively.

Comment: They all have to be zero to satisfy the condition. Edit: Changed to multiplication.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the guy who posted that wasn't OP

Comment: It's because you're use "!=" for comparing objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects can't be compared using `==` or `!=`. You have to use the `equals()` method:

```
if (!af.equals(zero) && !ae.equals(zero) && !be.equals(zero) {
  ...
}
```

The operators `!=` and (`==`) check for object identity, i.e. if both references point to the same instance. They don't compare the "value" of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

**LE:**
if 'af','ae' and 'be' are numbers (type int,double,float) you can use:

```
if(af != 0 && ae !=0 && be != 0)
```

but if they are objects, you can either compare their attributes by 0 or compare them with an object of the same type.See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Comment: he said that 'af', 'ae' and 'be' are integers, but after edit it looks like they are objects

Comment: Yah, that's what I figure.  This is an extremely common mistake.  Just update your answer to fit his solution now

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if(! af.equals(zero) && ! ae.equals(zero) && ! be.equals(zero) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking if they are all zero, just multiply them all together and if the result is zero, well you know...

I am assuming, since you did not provide your `MyDouble` class, that you have a method of retrieving the `value`?

```
if ((af.value() * ae.value() * be.value()) != 0)
```

**OP**, please provide us with your `MyDouble.java` class.

Comment: You cannot operator overload in java. This will not work with custom defined classes as the question states (now)

Comment: Well, I do not know how to return the value of OP's `MyDouble` so I assume that it is a "double"...